# Can we connect a single node in graph db with multiple nodes based on their ID

Tags: neo4j

I am currently working on **Neo4j** tool for developing a graph database.

I have a node "Course" and i want to connect this node with multiple nodes based on their ID's using a single query.

Is there any way or query in specific to perform the above task?

Comment: Yes, that should be an easy operation. Can you share what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example Cypher query that selects one start node and multiple end nodes based on their internal ID, and adds an edge with name RELATED from the start node to each end node:

```
MATCH (n),(m) WHERE ID(n)=1 AND ID(m) IN [2,3] CREATE (n)-[:RELATED]->(m)
```